# Solr parameter issuse

Tags: solr, parameters, solrj, solrcloud

```
entity name = "sp" 
query = "Select * from txn_ds_platter" 
deltaImportQuery = "SELECT * FROM txn_ds_platter WHERE member_id = ${dataimporter.request.i_member_id}"
```

url : http://localhost:8983/solr/search/select?q=%3A&fq=i_member_id%3A+15603&wt=json&indent=true

> Error : undefined field i_member_id.

Please help me out.

Comment: This error means the specified field isn't defined in schema.xml. If it is defined in schema.xml, then you need to restart your Solr server.

Comment: your first snippet is a piece of db-data-config.xml, which is used for DIH indexing off a db etc. But your url is a search request, not a request for the DIH to index.

Comment: I cannot tell what is code, what is error text and what is configuration. Please put a bit more effort in the question. The way it is, it is not solvable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to trigger a Data Request Handler with additional parameters.

The problem is that you seem to be using wrong end-point (Request Handler) for that. You are using **select** end point, where you should be using **dataimport** or whatever your solrconfig.xml defines. Here is one from DIH/DB example:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

So, if your core is called *search* you probably want to call:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/search/dataimport?command=full-import&i_member_id=15603
```

Comment: how to pass additional parameters in solr for search.  http://localhost:8983/solr/search/select?q=%3A&fq=i_member_id%3A+15603&wt=json&indent=true